# Using UseNavigation to navigate to a specific screen

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

```
const navigation = useNavigation(); 
navigation.navigate('Profile')}
```

getting this error on .navigate

```
No overload matches this call.
Argument of type '[string]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(options: never): void', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

the navigation prop that we get props works without any problems, but i want to use this in a component that is not a screen

my react navigation version

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.18",
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution is use. I add the `as never` tag after the navigation page name. It isn't the best solution but the error is gone.

```js
navigation.navigate('Profile' as never)}
```